# LinearLayout inside TableRow makes a warning

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make a custom TableRow for my android application. I started from the LinearLayout which is exactly what I want to display but as a TableRow in a TableLayout.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:text="@string/Context" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ContextTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:text="@string/SHUId" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/SHUIdTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.3" />
    </LinearLayout>

    ...Others LinearLayouts with 2 TextViews...

</LinearLayout>
```

So first I tried to put this code inside a TableRow element :

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    ...LinearLayout code from above...

<TableRow />
```

At this point the layout is displayed properly in the eclipse editor BUT now I have a Lint warning on the main LinearLayout : "This LinearLayout layout or its TableRow parent is 
 useless"

Then I'd say OK TableRow is a subclass of LinearLayout then I could simply remove the main LinearLayout and put his properties directly on the TableRow just like this :

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout >
        <TextView />
        <TextView />
    <LinearLayout />

    <LinearLayout >
        <TextView />
        <TextView />
    <LinearLayout />

    ...etc...

<TableRow />
```

But now the layout is not correctly displayed anymore (but no warning). I see only the first line (with the 2 first TextView). 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your `TableRow` a child of `TableLayout`? If not you shouldn't be using `TableRow` - without `TableLayout` it's just a horizontal `LinearLayout`.

Comment: I programmatically add the TableRow inside a TableLayout but in my XML file it's just a single TableRow

Comment: Then if it's a horizontal LinearLayout, is it possible that the property android:orientation="vertical" is not taken into account ?

Comment: well, you have your answer, TableRow is a horizontal LinearLayout and your outmost LinearLayout is a vertical one - when you remove it, you don't see your second row because it's far on the right in horizontal TableRow. Leave your outmost LinearLayout and nevermind the warning.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't take this into account and proposes to remove either one of the layouts.

Comment: actually yes, it seems like the property android:layout_width="match_parent" of the main LinearLayout is not taken into account. The TableRow seems to have the good width but not its inner LineraLayout.

Comment: From the docs:

The children of a TableRow do not need to specify the layout_width and layout_height attributes in the XML file. TableRow always enforces those values to be respectively MATCH_PARENT and WRAP_CONTENT.

Comment: even if I don't set these 2 properties, it's still the same : the inner LinearLayout is shrunk to one third of the width of the screen. For now, I put the width to 320dp but that won't fit every screen sizes...

Comment: post your current layout, i'll take a look.

Comment: I was trying to put a LinearLayout orientation="vertical" inside a TableRow and apparently it does not like it. Then I used directly a LinearLayout orientation="vertical" inside the TableLayout and it went just fine.